# Is PayFlow Pro supported in France?

Tags: payflowpro

Hi I am in France and want to create a merchant account in PayFlow Pro but there is no option in countries list for France. My question is PayFlow Pro not supported in France. And if it is not is there any other way to register for the merchant account living in France? Because the countries are mandatory to select. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Pro 3.0 is available in France.
PayFlow, not yet, probalby during next year it will be available too.

see:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/

Comment: Yes I am asking specifically about PayFlow Pro merchant account.

Comment: Website Payments Pro and Payflow Gateway are still not available in most countries, here is a working link: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/howto_product_matrix/